# best way to hide form if li class exists?

Tags: jquery

I have the following li class:

```
<li class="main clazz tab_new">
    <a href="/requests/new" class="tab">Submit a request</a>
</li>
```

I wish to hide the following form if the above li exists.

```
<div class="content content_grey">
    <div class="grey_box_top">
        <div class="box box_top"></div></div>  
<div class="login-container">
    <div class="login-form">
        <form class="new_user" id="password-form">
```

Please help i've tried a few different ways but no luck.

Comment: *Show us* what you've tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know which class you are selecting the li based on, but if it's "tab_new" then this will work:

```
if ($("li.tab_new").length) {
    $("form#password-form").hide();
}
```